# Error: Compile Error: No such column 'Assignee__c' on entity 'Task'

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, callout

I am trying to synchronize salesforce task comments to Jira issues comments and I am getting the following error when I am trying to save the apex class:

> Error: Compile Error: No such column 'Assignee__c' on entity 'Task'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 9 column 21

I have the following Apex class:

```
global class JIRATaskWebserviceCalloutSyncFields {
    @future (callout=true)
    WebService static void syncfields(String JIRA_Key) {
        //Modify these variables:
        String username = 'yourusername';
        String password = 'yourpassword';
        String jiraURL = ' http://youjiraurl.com';

        sObject s = [SELECT Subject, Assignee__c, Priority, Requested_By__c FROM Task WHERE JIRA_Key__c = :JIRA_key LIMIT 1];
        String c_summary = (String) s.get('Subject');
        String c_assignee = (String) s.get('Assignee__c');
        String c_priority = (String) s.get('Priority');
        String c_requested_by = (String) s.get('Requested_By__c');

         String priorityId;
        //Map Salesforce Prority to JIRA Prority
        if (c_priority  == 'Blocker') {                 // Salesforce.com Priority
            priorityId = '1';                           // JIRA Priority ID
        } else if (c_priority  == 'Critical') {
            priorityId = '2';
        } else if (c_priority  == 'Major') {
            priorityId = '3';
        } else if (c_priority == 'Minor') {
            priorityId = '4';
        } else if (c_priority == 'Trivial') {
            priorityId = '5';
        }

        //Construct HTTP request and response
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        //Construct Authorization and Content header
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username+':'+password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');


        //Construct Endpoint
        String endpoint = jiraURL+'/rest/api/2/issue/'+JIRA_Key;

        //Set Method and Endpoint and Body
        req.setMethod('PUT');
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setBody('{ \"fields\":{\"summary\": \"'+c_summary+'\", \"assigne\":{\"name\":\"'+c_assignee+'\"}, \"priority\":{\"id\":\"'+priorityId+'\"}, \"customfield_10400\":{\"value\":\"'+c_requested_by+'\"}}}');

        try {
            //Send endpoint to JIRA
            res = http.send(req);
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('ERROR:' + e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

In the error, the line 9 with the Assignee__C is basically a case field(apex class is also designed for case, and I replaced the case with Task),I trying to clone this onto Task. And Task doesn't have the Assignee__C field. How can get rid of this criteria in order to save the class

Comment: Thanx for the edit @adrian!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the references to it. You have three:

1. **Query**

   ```
   SELECT Subject, Assignee__c, ...
   ```

   Change to:

   ```
   SELECT Subject, ...
   ```
2. **Getter**

   ```
   String c_assignee = (String) s.get('Assignee__c');
   ```

   Just remove this line entirely
3. **JSON**

   ```
   '...'+c_summary+'\", \"assigne\":{\"name\":\"'+c_assignee+'\"}, \"priority\":...'
   ```

   Remove the `{"name": <c_assignee>}` portion of this markup.

   ```
   '...'+c_summary+'\", \"priority\":...'
   ```

Also, it's much easier to work with JSON if you create classes to serialize to/from.

Comment: Hello @Adrian, Should I also remove "Requested by" and its respective references. I don't have that anywhere.

Comment: @abhi Surely you can extend the pattern to figure out how to remove that field as well...

Answer (score 1):

If this class is only designed for Tasks simply remove the field, **but you may want the Task Owner Name or owner.Name so use that**

```
global class JIRATaskWebserviceCalloutSyncFields {
    @future (callout=true)
    WebService static void syncfields(String JIRA_Key) {
        //Modify these variables:
        String username = 'venkatdavuluri';
        String password = 'Wildcraft@987';
        String jiraURL = ' http://jira.hdwuotecenter.com';

        sObject s = [SELECT Subject, Owner.Name, Priority, Requested_By__c FROM Task WHERE JIRA_Key__c = :JIRA_key LIMIT 1];
        String c_summary = (String) s.get('Subject');
        String c_assignee = (String) s.get('Owner.Name');
        String c_priority = (String) s.get('Priority');
        String c_requested_by = (String) s.get('Requested_By__c');

        ...................

        req.setBody('{ \"fields\":{\"summary\": \"'+c_summary+'\", \"assigne\":{\"name\":\"'+c_assignee+'\"}, \"priority\":{\"id\":\"'+priorityId+'\"}, \"customfield_10400\":{\"value\":\"'+c_requested_by+'\"}}}');


      ....................      

    }
}
```